# Drupal get module info?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there any function in Drupal like `get_module_info('MODULE_NAME')` or I should parse `info` file?

Comment: What module info do you want to get?

Comment: I've been developing a module which sorts out information on existing modules and return information based on info file.

Comment: I think It would be great if there any implementation on this kinda get_info('module OR theme', 'MODULE NAME or THEME NAME')

Comment: If you don't tell what info you would like an API to give you, it's quite hard to help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`drupal_parse_info_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_parse_info_file/6.x) is the closest function, but it takes a file path, not a module name, so you have to convert the name into the path first:

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', $name) . '/' . $name . '.info';
$info = drupal_parse_info_file($path);
```

Answer (score 7):

A somewhat easier method (drupal 7 and up) is to use the [system_get_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_get_info/7) function.

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to be using the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, it has created a solid structure for interacting with the System table that is readily adaptable for any module info gathering.

To get information about a module, use `features_get_modules($module_name)`. This dispatches a module-specific request to `features_get_info()` on line 475 of features.module.

The information is cached, and you can make use of hook_system_info_alter() to modify the values you need. Note that this functionality is not touched by anything in Drupal core, and is only useful for your own custom module functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8.6+:

```php
$info = \Drupal::service("extension.list.module")->getExtensionInfo('mymodule');
```